# Python 2.8 - updating code sample from v. 2.63 (image rendering and saving)

Tags: python, rendering, eevee-render-engine

In 2.8, I am having difficulty adapting a code sample written for Blender/Python 2.63.  The intent is to save images of a scene using python.  The code was sourced from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14982836/rendering-and-saving-images-through-blender-python) post.

In 2.8, the code throws an error on the following line.  The error message is 'AttributeError: 'SpaceView3D' object has no attribute 'viewport_shade''

```
area.spaces[0].viewport_shade = 'RENDERED'
```

The full code snippet is here:

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        area.spaces[0].viewport_shade = 'RENDERED'

bpy.context.scene.render.image_settings.file_format='JPEG'
bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = ".pic%0.2d.jpg"%i
bpy.ops.render.render(use_viewport = True, write_still=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line to set the viewport shading needs to change from

```
area.spaces[0].viewport_shade = 'RENDERED'
```

to

```
area.spaces[0].shading.type = 'RENDERED'
```

since Blender 2.8's API has replaced `viewport_shade`. Here you can find the documentation of the [`Area`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Area.html#bpy.types.Area), [`AreaSpaces`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.AreaSpaces.html#bpy.types.AreaSpaces), [`SpaceView3D`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.SpaceView3D.html?highlight=shading#bpy.types.SpaceView3D.shading) (if the `space` is of type 'VIEW_3D') and [`View3DShading`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.View3DShading.html#bpy.types.View3DShading.type).

Although I'm wondering why you'd want to set the viewport shading if you intend to actually render the scene. In case this really is what you want I'd suggest getting the active space, which will be the one currently displayed.

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas: 
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        space = area.spaces.active
        space.shading.type = 'RENDERED'
```

Comment: Thanks for your help ... both suggestions work.  As far as why I chose the first, I am a noob and am as of yet still developing an understanding of this rather complicated piece of software ;)